# Why can't I use a variable in an for x in df.itertuples loop created prior to that loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

This is probably a basic Pandas question but I can't figure it out?

I have this loop :

```
n=0
for lum in lum_df.itertuples():
    print(lum.X)
    print(lum.Y)
    lum_x = float(lum.X)
    lum_y = float(lum.Y)
    for point in street_df.itertuples():
        print(point.X)
        print(point.Y)
        print(lum_x)
        print(lum_y)
        dist = calculate_dist(lum_x, point.X, lum_y, point.Y)
        print('DISTANCE IS : ' + str(dist))
        print('================= next point================')
    print('=============NEXT LUM==============')
```

Somehow, when I try to compte the distance between the 2 points in the second for loop, the values (lum_x and lum_y) are returned as nan. I would need to find a way to use these previously created variables in the second loop. Why doesn't it allow me to do so and what can I do about it?

PS: the point.x and point.y are already float variables !

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead try `for ix, lum in lum_df.iterrows():`.

Comment: unfortunately it returns me : too manu values to unpack (expected 2)?

Comment: Interesting, I'll post an example in a larger comment.

Comment: There are no reasons for that. It is likely that you do have NaNs in your dataframes or that conversions of your actual values give NaN. And I cannot say more without a [mcve]. And ideally we need to be able to produce the lines from you dataframes which cause the errors *with their exact type*, or at least you should say what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the data structure of lum_df :

```
                    X                 Y          Name
624  617053.712042883  5027348.30038856  AvenuedAnjou
664  617039.606222975    5027394.710913  AvenuedAnjou
692  617033.143825697  5027442.18526991  AvenuedAnjou
723  617024.347605215  5027483.05113423  AvenuedAnjou
751   617006.33108007  5027520.85562618  AvenuedAnjou
```

and when I run this variation :

```
#Boucle 2
n=0
for ix, lum in lum_df.itertuples():
    print(lum.X)
    print(lum.Y)
    lum_x = float(lum.X)
    lum_y = float(lum.Y)
    distmin=2000000
    nopoint=0
    exit()
    for point in street_df.itertuples():
        print(point.X)
        print(point.Y)
        print(lum_x)
        print(lum_y)
        dist = calculate_dist(lum_x, point.X, lum_y, point.Y)
        print('DISTANCE IS : ' + str(dist))
        print('================= next point================')
    print('=============NEXTLUM==============')
```

I get :

```
    for ix, lum in lum_df.itertuples():
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please edit you original question to add clarification, don't post an *answer*. You *must provide a [mcve]* or else the question is off-topic

Comment: This error is caused because iterrows and itertuples have different semantics. `itertuples` returns an iterable of rows (pd.Series), while `iterrows` returns an iterable of tuples (index, row). Emma suggested you to use iterrows but you only used one half of what she said...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

lum_df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
street_df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'Y': [9, 10, 11, 12]})

for ix, lum in lum_df.iterrows():
    print(float(lum.X))
    print(float(lum.Y))
    for ix, point in street_df.iterrows():
        print(point.X)
        print(point.Y)
```

Comment: Very sorry if I posted an answer. I'll keep in mind to be more minimalistic in my approach. Thanks for your input Emma, it solved it.